# Detect & Prevent Browser 'Back' and Close Tab Button Clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

BEFORE you assume the worst, most slimy hackish intents, just know I need to do this to prevent duplicate purchases and to keep my tracking data CLEAN.

As the title suggests, I am looking to an updated, elegant way to listen for and handle back button clicks OR browser tab closes.

I.E. If the user clicks either, they are immediately redirected AWAY from the current page they are on and onto a different page of my choosing.

Most of the answers I found rely on having access to the page the user visited before, or on other listeners that fire on ALL navigational events, not just the specific events I want to target.

Is there a newer, more elegant solution?

Comment: There is no way to detect those specific user actions from the window. You might want to use [`navigator.sendBeacon()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) which is more reliable than `unload` event ajax. You certainly can't have user sent to another page when they try to close a tab. That would get abused heavily and cause user to lose control of browser

Comment: You can add history to the page, so when the use clicks the back button you can listen for that. So for example, the page loads and some user interaction adds a hash to the url of the page. When the user clicks the back button, rather than going back to the previous page, they just remove the hash. You could listen for that and act accordingly. See this: https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/03/how-to-manage-the-back-button-with-javascript/ although it is written back to front for what you are trying to do it should help you. Not sure about closing the tab though...

Comment: Perhaps you could use websockets or similar to connect the page with the server so the server knows when the page has been closed and cleans up your data.  Don't have details, but something worth looking into.

Comment: I've done some digging and asked some friends @charlietfl and they pointed me to this website. I have NO idea how they are doing this https://diyhomeenergy.com/System/

Comment: @jperry1147 please read my comment above

Comment: @freedomn-m please read my comment above

Comment: Doing what exactly? Showing the popup? You can listen to a blur event on the window to do that but is not doing what you originally asked

Comment: @charlietfl when I click on the back button it takes me to a different page on their website.

Comment: They are listening for a mouseout when the mouse position is above the top of the page. Like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36263255/1616772

I wonder if it would be possible to somehow have the user edit a form which when they went to close or go back, the browser would ask them to confirm and you could listen for that...?